# Automatic deletion of old backups in Sublime Text

Tags: backup, sublime-text

Using the disk analyzer to clean some garbage I found some (automatically made?) backups. At least I hadn't installed any backup package, so I suppose it must be safe to get rid of the older ones.
How can I configure Sublime Text to keep only the last N-backups?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Via sublime - you can't.

But you're on Ubuntu, so why not use `cron`? Add the following script (i.e. `clean_sublime_backups`) to `/etc/cron.daily`:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -t /home/YOURUSERNAME/.config/sublime-text-2/Backup/ | sed '1,5d' | xargs rm -r
```

Afterwards `chmod 755 /etc/cron.daily/clean_sublime_backups`. To change the number of Backups left, modify the `'1,5d'` part as `'1,YOURNUMBERd'`. Backups will be cleaned every day.